# PDO SELECT Error handling

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi I am trying to make sure that when a user logs into the site, that they are a user. with MYSQL it is easy, but I have to use PDO, and I am struggling on figuring out how to get it to throw to the error message and not log the user in.

I have included the PHP select statement below..

```
$sql = "SELECT C.cid,C.first_name,C.sirname, S.sid 
         FROM CUSTOMER as C, 
              STAFF as S  
         WHERE C.email_address='".$email_address."' 
          AND C.password='".$password."' 
          AND S.CUSTOMER_CID=C.cid";

$runsql = static::db();
$runsql->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//self::get()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
    foreach ($runsql->query($sql) as $row) {
        /*if ($result = $runsql->prepare("SELECT C.cid,C.first_name,C.sirname, S.sid FROM CUSTOMER as C, STAFF as S  WHERE C.email_address='".$email_address."' AND C.password='".$password."' AND S.CUSTOMER_CID   =C.cid")) {
        */
        //print_r($runsql);
        //Check to make sure the user is on the staff list.
        $_SESSION['customer_id'] = $row->cid;
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row->first_name;
        $_SESSION['last_name']  = $row->sirname;
        $_SESSION['sid']  = $row->sid;
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    /* If PDO fails we handle it here */
    echo "Your query failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: There is not much point moving to PDO and keeping all the SQL Injection issues you had when using `mysql_` Look at prepared statement and parameterized variables

Comment: A `SELECT` query not matching any rows **is not an error** and hence there won't be any exception thrown. You'll simply get zero result rows. That should really be no different from the way you did it with `mysql`...

Comment: Also setting scalar variables in a loop makes no sence, You will only see the values in the `$_SESSION` variables from the LAST ROW of your queries result set. **Is that actually the problem here?????** _That would also have applied if you were using the **so called easier mysql**_

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't store password as is but hash it using password_hash()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to understand that it is not an error if user not found. It never was so with old mysql ext and neither with PDO. What you have to check is not an error but whether your query returned anything.

To do so you need only one single call to `fetch()`.

```
$sql = "SELECT C.cid,C.first_name,C.sirname, S.sid 
         FROM CUSTOMER as C, STAFF as S  
         WHERE C.email_address=? AND C.password=? 
         AND S.CUSTOMER_CID=C.cid";
$stmt = static::db()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$email_address,$password]);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if ($row)
{
        $_SESSION['customer_id'] = $row->cid;
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row->first_name;
        $_SESSION['last_name']  = $row->sirname;
        $_SESSION['sid']  = $row->sid;
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
} else {
    echo "wrong credentials";
}
```

Note that you have to set ATTR_ERRMODE right after connect and never change it.

While real error handling is a different matter which is in general irrelevant to PDO and have to be the same for the whole site.